# delete data from Bigquery table that has all column matching value

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud

I have a table in BigQuery and that has total 620 columns. I need to delete duplicate records that has all 620 columns with matching values. Can anyone help me on this. thanks

Comment: Can you calculate a hash on a row and use it to get distinct rows?

Comment: hash, concatenate,... create a unique value for each row, and do a distinct

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
select * from your_table t
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by format('%t', t))
```

another option is

```
select as value any_value(t)
from your_table t
group by format('%t', t)
```